# How can i transfer one gridview row to another gridview row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two grid views :

1. `gvdetails` and
2. `gvTranferRows`

`gvdetails` are bind from selected database. The fields are :

- `id`,
- `moduleName` and
- `Item` fields.

In `gvTransferRows` fields are :

- `id`,
- `ModuleName`,
- `Item` and
- `BatchNo`.

`BatchNo` is selected from `dropdownlist`.

But I want to transfer selected rows from `gvdetails` to `gvTranferRows`.

In this process I successfully remove and add `gvdetails` selected rows to `gvTranferRows` by clicking remove button at same time and vice versa.

But after clicking the remove button it done and again same operation to second time clicking the add button the `gvdetails` gridview will completely remove it transfer to `gvTransferRows`.

What I need is to select second time in add button, it will not remove only selected values remove and transfer to second gridview.

This is the code I tried for code :

**.aspx:**

```
  <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2"></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbatchno" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="131px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2" valign="top">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ModuleName" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleName" HeaderText="ModuleName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
                                  <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchNo" HeaderText="BatchNo" />

                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6699ff" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Text="ADD" />
                        <br />
                        <label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &gt;&gt;<br />
                        <br />
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" OnClick="btnRemove_Click"  Text="Remove" />
                        <br />
                        <label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;&lt;</label> </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvTranferRows" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ModuleName" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleName" HeaderText="ModuleName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchNo" HeaderText="BatchNo" />
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6699ff" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <br />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

.cs page:

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    ddlbatch();
                    BindGridview();
                    BindSecondGrid();
                }
            }
public void ddlbatch()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select BatchNo from Batches", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            ddlbatchno.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            ddlbatchno.DataTextField = "BatchNo";
            ddlbatchno.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            ddlbatchno.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select batche no--", "0"));
        }

        protected void BindGridview() //Binding gvDetaails gridview
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,ModuleName,Item,BatchNo from ModuleItems", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            ViewState["dt1"] = dt;
            gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
        }



        protected void BindSecondGrid() // binding gvtransfer gridview
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["GetRecords"];
            gvTranferRows.DataSource = dt;
            gvTranferRows.DataBind();

        }

        string name; 
   protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);
                    if (chkRow.Checked)
                    {

                        int totalCount = gvDetails.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Count(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked);

                        name += row.Cells[1].Text + ",";

                    }
                }
            }
            string[] name3 = name.Split(',');

            for (int l = 0; l < name3.Length; l++)
            {

                string str = "UPDATE ModuleItems SET BatchNo = " + ddlbatchno.SelectedItem.ToString() + " WHERE id= '" + name3[l] + "'";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                con.Open();

                int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow oItemLeft in gvDetails.Rows)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)oItemLeft.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
                {
                    GetSelectedRows();
                    BindSecondGrid();
                    break;
                }

            }

            DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable; //2nd time adding gvdetails to gvtransfer dt will become null

            if (dt != null)
            {
                for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
                    string dtname = row["id", DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
                    string[] name1 = name.Split(',');
                    for (int l = 0; l < name1.Length; l++)
                    {
                        string name2 = name1[l].ToString();
                        if (dtname == name2)
                        {
                            row.Delete();

                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            ViewState["dt"] = dt;

            gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
        }   
        private void GetSelectedRows()
        {
            DataTable dt;
            if (ViewState["GetRecords"] != null)
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["GetRecords"];
            else
                dt = CreateTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    dt = AddGridRow(gvDetails.Rows[i], dt);
                }

            }
            ViewState["GetRecords"] = dt;
        }
        private DataTable CreateTable()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("ModuleName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Item");
            dt.Columns.Add("BatchNo");

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            return dt;
        }

        private DataTable AddGridRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
        {
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
            if (dr.Length <= 0)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int rowscount = dt.Rows.Count - 1;
                dt.Rows[rowscount]["id"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
                dt.Rows[rowscount]["ModuleName"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
                dt.Rows[rowscount]["Item"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
                dt.Rows[rowscount]["BatchNo"] = ddlbatchno.SelectedItem.Text;
                dt.AcceptChanges();


            }
            return dt;
        }

        protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (gvTranferRows.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTranferRows.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        CheckBox chkRow1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect2") as CheckBox);
                        if (chkRow1.Checked)
                        {

                            int totalCount = gvTranferRows.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Count(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSelect2")).Checked);

                            name += row.Cells[1].Text + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }
                string[] name3 = name.Split(',');
                foreach (GridViewRow oItemLeft in gvTranferRows.Rows)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)oItemLeft.FindControl("chkSelect2")).Checked)
                    {
                        GetRemoveRows();

                        BindGridview();
                        //break;
                    }

                }
                DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
                for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
                    string dtname = row["id", DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
                    string[] name1 = name.Split(',');
                    for (int l = 0; l < name1.Length; l++)
                    {
                        string name2 = name1[l].ToString();
                        if (dtname != name2)
                        {
                            row.Delete();

                        }
                    }

                }


                ViewState["dt"] = dt;

                gvTranferRows.DataSource = dt;
                gvTranferRows.DataBind();

            }
        }


        DataTable dt,dt1;

        private void GetRemoveRows()
        {


            if (ViewState["GetRecords"] != null)
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["GetRecords"];

               ViewState["GetRecords"] = dt;
                ViewState["GetRecords2"] = dt;
                gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
                gvDetails.DataBind();
            this. ViewState.Remove("GetRecords2"); //for  viewstate control

            ViewState["GetRecords2"] = null;//for variables 


        }
```

I am attaching my result image how the result will process. I posted full of my code can anyone please help me out.

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format lists, inline code and image so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use a temporary DataTable to maintain the list selected rows or records and then use the DataTable to bind the secondary GridView.

U will get more idea from here
[Transfer Selected Rows from one GridView to Another in Asp.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Transfer-Selected-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-Another-in-Asp.net.aspx)

[Another way to transfer data](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Transfer-Selected-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-Another-in-Asp.net.aspx)

Comment: all the data from the first grid will sent to second grid but how can we retrieve the data from second grid to first grid

Comment: i had tried even same code also transfer data from second grid to first grid but it not working.can you please help me out

Comment: @user123   http://www.codescratcher.com/windows-forms/transfer-selected-rows-one-gridview-another-gridview/

Answer (score 0):

Please try DataTable.ImportRow method:

[DataTable.ImportRow() on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.datatable.importrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'm using this method on many WebForms and MVC pages and it works great.